# Cascade multiple RNN models for N-dimensional output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I'm having some difficulty with chaining together two models in an unusual way.

I am trying to replicate the following flowchart:

[image: Cascaded RNN 2-D]

For clarity, at each timestep of `Model[0]` I am attempting to generate an entire time series from `IR[i]` (Intermediate Representation) as a repeated input using `Model[1]`.  The purpose of this scheme is it allows the generation of a ragged 2-D time series from a 1-D input (while both allowing the second model to be omitted when the output for that timestep is not needed, and not requiring `Model[0]` to constantly "switch modes" between accepting input, and generating output).

I assume a custom training loop will be required, and I already have a custom training loop for handling statefulness in the first model (the previous version only had a single output at each timestep).  As depicted, the second model should have reasonably short outputs (able to be constrained to fewer than 10 timesteps).

But at the end of the day, while I can wrap my head around what I want to do, I'm not nearly adroit enough with Keras and/or Tensorflow to actually implement it.  (In fact, this is my first non-toy project with the library.)

I have unsuccessfully searched literature for similar schemes to parrot, or example code to fiddle with.  And I don't even know if this idea is possible from within TF/Keras.

I already have the two models working in isolation. (As in I've worked out the dimensionality, and done some training with dummy data to get garbage outputs for the second model, and the first model is based off of a previous iteration of this problem and has been fully trained.) If I have `Model[0]` and `Model[1]` as python variables (let's call them `model_a` and `model_b`), then how would I chain them together to do this?

Edit to add:

If this is all unclear, perhaps having the dimensions of each input and output will help:

The dimensions of each input and output are:

Input: `(batch_size, model_a_timesteps, input_size)`
IR: `(batch_size, model_a_timesteps, ir_size)`

IR[i] (after duplication): `(batch_size, model_b_timesteps, ir_size)`
Out[i]: `(batch_size, model_b_timesteps, output_size)`
Out: `(batch_size, model_a_timesteps, model_b_timesteps, output_size)`

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the solution's either simple or quite complex; what is the desired _gradient_ behavior? i.e., do horizontal arrows denote a stateful gradient? If so, then you must backpropagate through several full forward passes, which is way beyond the scope of one question.

Comment: The desired behavior is that `Out[n][i]` depends on `IR[n]` and the hidden state from the previous iteration of `Model[1]`. And so on, like a normal RNN. `IR[n]` in turn depends on `Input[n]` and `H[n]` like a normal RNN. So the total gradients contributing to any particular output is essentially everything to the (logical) left and (logically) underneath the output. That being said, while `Model[0]` is stateful, for my particular use case it is not necessary to backpropagate beyond the beginning of a particular time batch to achieve good results. (`H[0]` can be treated as an immutable input)

Comment: So for `H[4]`, would you backpropagate through `H[3], H[2], H[1], H[0]`? And for `Out[2][2]`, through `Out[2][1], Out[2][0]`? Then you seek batch-to-batch backprop, which isn't natively implemented in tf.keras; RNN's `stateful` doesn't backpropagate between batches, and learns to work with various initializations rather than truly longer sequences. If this RNN behavior is what you seek, the task is simple - else, fairly complex, but doable within tf.keras by invoking TF ops.

Comment: I'm not certain I completely understand the bounds you're saying.  As a concrete example: `Out[1][1]` (ie. the stop) depends on both `IR[1]` and the hidden state from the previous iteration of the upper RNN (which depends on `IR[1]`), in turn `IR[1]` depends on `H[1]`, `H[0]`, `Input[1]` and `Input[0]`.  I'm looking to back propagate from `Out[1][1]` all of the way to the inputs, if this is possible.  Otherwise, I cannot see a way to train both networks (as I have no constraints on what `IR` can be).

Comment: So all of `Input` is a _single train step_, correct? I.e. weights aren't updated until `Input[-1]` is consumed.

Comment: That's the idea.  I'm splitting the input into timebatches (hence the `H[0]`), but this diagram already has that taken into account and is attempting to show a single train step.

Comment: Just to check if I understand correctly - is `Model[1]` dynamically unrolled until the network outputs the stop token? Or can we assume that we know this in advance?

Comment: Nice question, learned a fair bit from investigating - though I'd likely not touch it were it anything beneath maxed bounty. A "high-level" approach wouldn't do as I myself couldn't be sure gradients worked as intended, until fully implemented. Lastly, if you plan on more custom stuff, I strongly recommend ditching TensorFlow for Pytorch - and I don't even use Pytorch (yet). TF's just a lode of bugs and needless complications, and I heard to contrary of Pytorch from researchers, and will be switching. -- Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this question has multiple major parts, I've dedicated a Q&A to the core challenge: [stateful backpropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63222771/10133797). This answer focuses on implementing the variable output step length.

---

**Description**:

- As validated in Case 5, we can take a bottom-up first approach. First we feed the complete input to `model_a` (A) - then, feed its outputs as input to `model_b` (B), but this time *one step at a time*.
- Note that we must chain B's output steps *per* A's input step, not *between* A's input steps; i.e., in your diagram, gradient is to flow between `Out[0][1]` and `Out[0][0]`, but not between `Out[2][0]` and `Out[0][1]`.
- For computing loss it won't matter whether we use a ragged or padded tensor; we must however use a padded tensor for writing to TensorArray.
- Loop logic in code below is general; specific attribute handling and hidden state passing, however, is hard-coded for simplicity, but can be rewritten for generality.

*Code*: at bottom.

---

**Example**:

- Here we predefine the number of iterations for B per input from A, but we can implement any arbitrary stopping logic. For example, we can take a `Dense` layer's output from B as a hidden state and check if its L2-norm exceeds a threshold.
- Per above, if `longest_step` is unknown to us, we can simply set it, which is common for NLP & other tasks with a STOP token.

  - Alternatively, we may write to separate `TensorArrays` at every A's input with `dynamic_size=True`; see "point of uncertainty" below.
- A valid concern is, how do we know gradients flow correctly? Note that we've validate them for both vertical and horizontal in the linked Q&A, but it didn't cover multiple output steps per an input step, for multiple input steps. See below.

---

*Point of uncertainty*: I'm not entirely sure whether gradients interact between e.g. `Out[0][1]` and `Out[2][0]`. I did, however, verify that gradients *will not* flow horizontally if we write to separate `TensorArray`s for B's outputs per A's inputs (case 2); reimplementing for cases 4 & 5, grads will differ for *both* models, including lower one with a complete single horizontal pass.

Thus we must write to a unified `TensorArray`. For such, as there are no ops leading from e.g. `IR[1]` to `Out[0][1]`, I can't see how TF would trace it as such - so it seems we're safe. Note, however, that in below example, using `steps_at_t=[1]*6` *will* make gradient flow in the both model horizontally, as we're writing to a single `TensorArray` and passing hidden states.

The examined case is confounded, however, with B being stateful at all steps; lifting this requirement, we might *not* need to write to a unified `TensorArray` for all `Out[0]`, `Out[1]`, etc, but we must still test against something we know works, which is no longer as straightforward.

---

**Example [code]**:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#%%# Make data & models, then fit ###########################################
x0 = y0 = tf.constant(np.random.randn(2, 3, 4))
msn = MultiStatefulNetwork(batch_shape=(2, 3, 4), steps_at_t=[3, 4, 2])

#%%#############################################
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    outputs = msn(x0)
    # shape: (3, 4, 2, 4), 0-padded
    # We can pad labels accordingly.
    # Note the (2, 4) model_b's output shape, which is a timestep slice;
    # model_b is a *slice model*. Careful in implementing various logics
    # which are and aren't intended to be stateful.
```

---

**Methods**:

Not the cleanest, nor most optimal code, but it works; room for improvement.

More importantly: I implemented this in Eager, and have no idea how it'll work in Graph, and making it work for both can be quite tricky. If needed, just run in Graph and compare all values as done in the "cases".

```py
# ideally we won't `import tensorflow` at all; kept for code simplicity
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.util import nest
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops, tensor_array_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, SimpleRNN, SimpleRNNCell
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

#######################################################################
class MultiStatefulNetwork():
    def __init__(self, batch_shape=(2, 6, 4), steps_at_t=[]):
        self.batch_shape=batch_shape
        self.steps_at_t=steps_at_t

        self.batch_size = batch_shape[0]
        self.units = batch_shape[-1]
        self._build_models()

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        outputs = self._forward_pass_a(inputs)
        outputs = self._forward_pass_b(outputs)
        return outputs

    def _forward_pass_a(self, inputs):
        return self.model_a(inputs, training=True)

    def _forward_pass_b(self, inputs):
        return model_rnn_outer(self.model_b, inputs, self.steps_at_t)

    def _build_models(self):
        ipt = Input(batch_shape=self.batch_shape)
        out = SimpleRNN(self.units, return_sequences=True)(ipt)
        self.model_a = Model(ipt, out)

        ipt  = Input(batch_shape=(self.batch_size, self.units))
        sipt = Input(batch_shape=(self.batch_size, self.units))
        out, state = SimpleRNNCell(4)(ipt, sipt)
        self.model_b = Model([ipt, sipt], [out, state])

        self.model_a.compile('sgd', 'mse')
        self.model_b.compile('sgd', 'mse')


def inner_pass(model, inputs, states):
    return model_rnn(model, inputs, states)


def model_rnn_outer(model, inputs, steps_at_t=[2, 2, 4, 3]):
    def outer_step_function(inputs, states):
        x, steps = inputs
        x = array_ops.expand_dims(x, 0)
        x = array_ops.tile(x, [steps, *[1] * (x.ndim - 1)])  # repeat steps times
        output, new_states = inner_pass(model, x, states)
        return output, new_states

    (outer_steps, steps_at_t, longest_step, outer_t, initial_states,
     output_ta, input_ta) = _process_args_outer(model, inputs, steps_at_t)

    def _outer_step(outer_t, output_ta_t, *states):
        current_input = [input_ta.read(outer_t), steps_at_t.read(outer_t)]
        output, new_states = outer_step_function(current_input, tuple(states))

        # pad if shorter than longest_step.
        # model_b may output twice, but longest in `steps_at_t` is 4; then we need
        # output.shape == (2, *model_b.output_shape) -> (4, *...)
        # checking directly on `output` is more reliable than from `steps_at_t`
        output = tf.cond(
            tf.math.less(output.shape[0], longest_step),
            lambda: tf.pad(output, [[0, longest_step - output.shape[0]],
                                    *[[0, 0]] * (output.ndim - 1)]),
            lambda: output)

        output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(outer_t, output)
        return (outer_t + 1, output_ta_t) + tuple(new_states)

    final_outputs = tf.while_loop(
        body=_outer_step,
        loop_vars=(outer_t, output_ta) + initial_states,
        cond=lambda outer_t, *_: tf.math.less(outer_t, outer_steps))

    output_ta = final_outputs[1]
    outputs = output_ta.stack()
    return outputs


def _process_args_outer(model, inputs, steps_at_t):
    def swap_batch_timestep(input_t):
        # Swap the batch and timestep dim for the incoming tensor.
        # (samples, timesteps, channels) -> (timesteps, samples, channels)
        # iterating dim0 to feed (samples, channels) slices expected by RNN
        axes = list(range(len(input_t.shape)))
        axes[0], axes[1] = 1, 0
        return array_ops.transpose(input_t, axes)

    inputs = nest.map_structure(swap_batch_timestep, inputs)

    assert inputs.shape[0] == len(steps_at_t)
    outer_steps = array_ops.shape(inputs)[0]  # model_a_steps
    longest_step = max(steps_at_t)
    steps_at_t = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=tf.int32, size=len(steps_at_t)).unstack(steps_at_t)

    # assume single-input network, excluding states which are handled separately
    input_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=inputs.dtype,
        size=outer_steps,
        element_shape=tf.TensorShape(model.input_shape[0]),
        tensor_array_name='outer_input_ta_0').unstack(inputs)

    # TensorArray is used to write outputs at every timestep, but does not
    # support RaggedTensor; thus we must make TensorArray such that column length
    # is that of the longest outer step, # and pad model_b's outputs accordingly
    element_shape = tf.TensorShape((longest_step, *model.output_shape[0]))

    # overall shape: (outer_steps, longest_step, *model_b.output_shape)
    # for every input / at each step we write in dim0 (outer_steps)
    output_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=model.output[0].dtype,
        size=outer_steps,
        element_shape=element_shape,
        tensor_array_name='outer_output_ta_0')

    outer_t = tf.constant(0, dtype='int32')
    initial_states = (tf.zeros(model.input_shape[0], dtype='float32'),)

    return (outer_steps, steps_at_t, longest_step, outer_t, initial_states,
            output_ta, input_ta)


def model_rnn(model, inputs, states):
    def step_function(inputs, states):
        output, new_states = model([inputs, *states], training=True)
        return output, new_states

    initial_states = states
    input_ta, output_ta, time, time_steps_t = _process_args(model, inputs)

    def _step(time, output_ta_t, *states):
        current_input = input_ta.read(time)
        output, new_states = step_function(current_input, tuple(states))

        flat_state = nest.flatten(states)
        flat_new_state = nest.flatten(new_states)
        for state, new_state in zip(flat_state, flat_new_state):
            if isinstance(new_state, ops.Tensor):
                new_state.set_shape(state.shape)

        output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(time, output)
        new_states = nest.pack_sequence_as(initial_states, flat_new_state)
        return (time + 1, output_ta_t) + tuple(new_states)

    final_outputs = tf.while_loop(
        body=_step,
        loop_vars=(time, output_ta) + tuple(initial_states),
        cond=lambda time, *_: tf.math.less(time, time_steps_t))

    new_states = final_outputs[2:]
    output_ta = final_outputs[1]
    outputs = output_ta.stack()
    return outputs, new_states


def _process_args(model, inputs):
    time_steps_t = tf.constant(inputs.shape[0], dtype='int32')

    # assume single-input network (excluding states)
    input_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=inputs.dtype,
        size=time_steps_t,
        tensor_array_name='input_ta_0').unstack(inputs)

    # assume single-output network (excluding states)
    output_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=model.output[0].dtype,
        size=time_steps_t,
        element_shape=tf.TensorShape(model.output_shape[0]),
        tensor_array_name='output_ta_0')

    time = tf.constant(0, dtype='int32', name='time')
    return input_ta, output_ta, time, time_steps_t
```